# Is it possible to top align checkbox in SWT

Tags: java, checkbox, swt

is ist possible to top align the checkbox symbol in SWT? Currently the checkbox symbol in vertically centered. But I would like to have it on top.

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is possible:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Display display = new Display();

        Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setMinimumSize(1, 1);
        shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, false));

        Composite left = new Composite(shell, SWT.NONE);
        left.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));
        GridData gd = new GridData();
        gd.verticalAlignment = SWT.TOP;
        left.setLayoutData(gd);

        new Button(left, SWT.CHECK);

        Composite right = new Composite(shell, SWT.NONE);
        right.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));
        Label label = new Label(right, SWT.WRAP);
        label.setText("Lorem inpsum. Lorem inpsum. Lorem inpsum.\n Lorem inpsum. Lorem inpsum. Lorem inpsum. \nLorem inpsum. Lorem inpsum.\n Lorem inpsum. Lorem inpsum. Lorem inpsum. Lorem inpsum. Lorem inpsum. Lorem inpsum.\n Lorem inpsum. Lorem inpsum. Lorem inpsum.\n Lorem inpsum. Lorem inpsum. ");
        GridData gd2 = new GridData();
        gd2.verticalAlignment = SWT.TOP;
        label.setLayoutData(gd2);

        shell.pack();
        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch())
                display.sleep();
        }
    }
}
```

If you have another approach of creating widgets, and you want to make it working as you described, you need to post some code snippets.

Comment: Well I need to do it with the native Button widget

Comment: What do you mean native Button? I used native SWT Button.

Comment: You used a Button and a Label. What I need to have is new Button b = new Button(..., SWT.Check). ... b.setText("Lorem ipsum...")

Comment: I see. (you'd better clarify this things in your question next time, as it is not clear what are preconditions and expected result nad what is not actually working). As per you question: no, it is not possible to do it as you wish. You need to create your own widget with Button and Label (as showed) to mimic this behavior.